# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072EE2): The operation timed out HResult=-2147012889

Tags: vb.net, oracle, web-services, soap, vbscript

I have a weird one over here;

I have built a small vb.net app using classic vbscript to send Soap Strings across Oracle CRM On Demand.

Everything works perfectly fine on my machine or on any other machine which is not connected to a VPN or within a company network.

So when I try to run the app on another machine which is on a company network i get the following error;

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072EE2): The operation timed out

   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at App.OutlookSync.ProcessCalendar(Object objCalendar) in C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CRMSync\CRMSync\Form1.vb:line 150
   at App.OutlookSync.btn4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CRMSync\CRMSync\Form1.vb:line 2061
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18052 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
CRMSync
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Apps/CRMSync.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.50709.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18034 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18047 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18021 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
    Assembly Version: 14.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.0.4760.1000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook/14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll
----------------------------------------
office
    Assembly Version: 14.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.0.4760.1000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/office/14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/office.dll
----------------------------------------
CustomMarshalers
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/CustomMarshalers/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/CustomMarshalers.dll
----------------------------------------
```

So according to the above error desc., it failed on the LINE 150 which is;

objXMLDOC.send(SoapStr.ToString) - LINE 150
Also line 2061 is just calling the Private Sub which has the code for sending the SOAP request.

Now with that machine being connected to a restrictive VPN or connected to a restrictive company network, I understand that there could be one of the Proxies is not letting the Soap URLs pass through for some reason. 'BUT' I have tried to access every single URL (that i am using in my code) via IE and other browsers and I access them without any problems. And (if I am not wrong) VB.NET Apps is based on same/ default user settings as IE. With that said, i have also got the following in my "app.config" file which should hopefully consider to take same internet/proxy settings as set in IE;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.net>
      <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
      </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
```

Also, after searching for hours on web, it seems like there "MIGHT" be an issue with registry. But i am really not sure what exactly to go and deal with this further.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders for pointing that out. I am new to this site so must have missed the point. But do you have any idea on the original question?